# Install certificate automatically for JWS application

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

My JWS application jar is signed<sup>1</sup> and when I launch that certificate it does not ask for anything and simply throws an exception saying your application has been blocked.

If I install that certificate it works, but how I force my application to give a message to install certificate so that it is installed automatically? I want something like as shown below.

1. I have created a certificate using keytool -genkey and then using jarsigner signed that jar file.

[image]

Comment: you mean get the certificate from certificate authority and using jarsigner sign the jar (the same way I did it using my own certificate), I have another question 1. How does javaws know that this certificate is issues by certificate authority or its a certificate created using keytool and if it is then only show that popup(as shown in the image)? 2.) How can I get those certificate for free ?

Comment: SO is a Q&A site rather than a help desk.  Ask separate questions on separate question threads.

Comment: apologies, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have created a certificate..

These days, signed code needs to be signed using a digital certificate issued by a certification authority. There is really no way around it (or if there was, it would be a security bug - and be quickly fixed).

The digital certificate created by us as developers has no 'key chain' that points back to a Certification Authority that issues certificates after verifying the identity of the person that requested the certificate.  Because CAs are trusted to check these details, Sun/Oracle imports some of their 'root certificates' into the JRE security system.  Any certificate that has a key chain that points back to one of those certificates will show the dialog as seen in the screen shot.

It is all about security for the end user.  Since I can generate a certificate with the JDK claiming **I** am **you,** the JRE won't accept the certificate no matter who makes it - *unless the certificate has been issued by a CA.*